# Spring batch FlatfileitemReader to read malformed lines

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, filereader, spring-batch-excel

In my project, I am using Spring batch and reading a file using FlatFileItemReader/FieldSetMapper. There is problem with some input files.The lines are cut/malformed for few records.
Assume the input file has 4 columns. few columns not formed properly. Can anyone please helpme in fixing this issue?(I could explain more if needed)
File.csv

```
"id","name","age","salary"
"1","user1","28","1000"
"2","user2","27","2000"
"3","user3","26
    ","3000"
"4","user4","25","
    4000"
"5","
        user5","24","5000"
"6","user6","23","6000"
"7","user7","22","7000"
"8","user8","21","8000"
```

Comment: Use an ItemProcessor<?,?> and just log the input data to find out if it is filled.

Comment: Then check with your columns Type in your destination.Maybe some data is lost during casting

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue while reading malformed lines with FlatFileItemReader.
In this case, you can use a DefaultRecordSeparatorPolicy as a RecordSeparatorPolicy in FlatFileItemReader. What it does is it checks for endOfRecord after reading a line. If the read line has any uncommented quotes, it reads the another line to normalize the input. You can also override the behavior.

`flatFileItemReader.setRecordSeparatorPolicy(new DefaultRecordSeparatorPolicy());`

Refer [DefaultRecordSeparatorPolicy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/separator/DefaultRecordSeparatorPolicy.html) API Doc for more information

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<YourClassName> itemReader(@Value("${input}") Resource resource) {
    FlatFileItemReader<YourClassName> flatFileItemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
    flatFileItemReader.setResource(resource);
    flatFileItemReader.setName("CSV-Reader");
    flatFileItemReader.setLinesToSkip(1);
    // override default comment '#' from file parsing
    flatFileItemReader.setComments(new String[] {});
    // checks for multi-line csv inputs for very lage row
    flatFileItemReader.setRecordSeparatorPolicy(new DefaultRecordSeparatorPolicy());
    flatFileItemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper());
    return flatFileItemReader;
}

@Bean
public LineMapper<YourClassName> lineMapper() {
    DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
    lineTokenizer.setDelimiter(DelimitedLineTokenizer.DELIMITER_COMMA);
    lineTokenizer.setQuoteCharacter(DelimitedLineTokenizer.DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER);
    lineTokenizer.setStrict(false);
    lineTokenizer.setNames(COLUMN_NAMES);

    BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<YourClassName> fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
    fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(YourClassName.class);

    DefaultLineMapper<YourClassName> defaultLineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
    defaultLineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
    defaultLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);
    return defaultLineMapper;
}
```